# iPhone/iOS/Safari won't change display:none to display:block using :hover

Tags: html, ios, css, iphone

I'm working on a responsive design that has fixed layers to keep the heading floating on the top of the page.  The menu and other information should show when hovering using the :hover and the element - so the display changes from none to block.

Does anyone know why Safari won't work correctly on iPhone?  I've tested on ever other device/browser I have access to without any problems.  Is there any other work around?  Maybe the use of Javascript?

The link is:
http://www.surfbagel.com/new/master.htm

Thank you for your time and help!

John

Comment: Please put some of the relavent code into your question: what div are you attempting to have switch: searching through your code to try and guess which part you mean ourselves is massively inefficient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a mobile device you don't have a `:hover`. The `hover` concept doesn't exist. Thats why in iPhone doesn't work.

Comment: So basically, this effect can't be created without using Javascript?  I've tried the other pseudoclasses with no luck.  Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that mobile Safari has [no concept of a hover](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2012/07/05/ios-has-a-hover-problem/).  If you think about it, how can you hover with a touch device ? With a mouse it's easy as you are not committing a click when you move your mouse around, but with Touch you are committing an action as soon as you touch the screen.

Answer (score 1):

You can't hover with an iPhone. You can try using :active instead of :hover.

In your case: For the menu, you'll have to add a class to the menu and change the class with Javascript from active to non-active, where the css of this class will change it from being display:none to display: block